# Redirect SSH connexion to another port in function of (sub)domaine

Tags: ssh, proxy, port, redirection

Let me explain what I'm trying to do ; first, I don't want a solution like editing `.ssh/config` to write a default port for specific domains client side, my question is specific to server side :)

**The context**

On a distant server, I got the SSH service running on port 22.
But I have a Docker service that want to expose its own SSH service. I cannot bind container:22 on host:22 (conflict), so I bind container:22 on host:2222.

But, on my company network, network traffic on port 2222 is locked.

**The question**

How, on the distant server, accept SSH connexion on port 22 by default, AND redirect on another port internally in function of domain or sub-domain called ?

Not sure a simple Nginx proxy will work for SSH protocol...

Thanks !

Comment: It depends what kind of devices are available on your network between the client and the server. If you have an F5 load balancer for instance, you could easily do this on the NLB level. On the server level, dynamically redirecting incoming connections based on domain and whatnot is not a viable strategy. 

Option 1 : Find another port that is allowed on the firewall and use that instead

Option 2 : SSH to the docker machine on the regular port 22, and then use docker ssh to connect to your container

Option 3: Give us a top level analysis of your network topology

Comment: Can you explain why "dynamically redirecting incoming connections based on domain and whatnot is not a viable strategy" ? And I don't understand what you want as "network topology" :/ I search a way more generic than finding another port specific to my company...

Comment: You can't do port forwarding based on the hostname, because when the connection reaches the server, the server doesn't know what hostname your client used, only the incoming IP and port. Another option would be to use different NICs on the docker machine and bind the containers on different IPs

Comment: If you talk about https://docs.docker.com/machine/, I don't use that ; I just have a server on which I'm connect via SSH on port 22, and try to start a Gitlab CE dockerized (and it expect an SSH port to clone project with public key)

Comment: Instead of such redirects why do not map docker SSH to port 443. Probably company roles will pass those packets :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov 'cuz port 443 already in use ;)

Comment: @Doubidou, consider SMTP over SSL/TLS, POP over SSL/TLS ports also